# "missing the right parenthesis" in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I've uploaded all my code. I think I'm using Oracle SQL Developer, which isn't the right one I'm assuming?

It's for a university assignment.

```
--CREATESCRIPTS

CREATE TABLE Bug --Creating the bug table.
(
Bug_ID  VARCHAR2 (6)NOT NULL,
Bug_Name VARCHAR2 (100)NOT NULL,
Bug_Desc VARCHAR2 (255)NOT NULL,
Found_Date DATE NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_Bug PRIMARY KEY (Bug_ID) --creating the primary key for Bug. 

);

CREATE TABLE Engineer --Creating the engineer table. 
 (
Engineer_ID VARCHAR2(6)NOT NULL,
Engineer_First VARCHAR2 (12)NOT NULL,
Engineer_Last VARCHAR2 (12)NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_Engineer PRIMARY KEY(Engineer_ID)

);

COMMIT;

CREATE TABLE Project --Creating the project table. 
(
Project_ID VARCHAR2 (8)NOT NULL,
Project_Name VARCHAR2(10)NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_Project PRIMARY KEY (Project_ID)

);

COMMIT;

CREATE TABLE Note --Creating the note table. 
(
Note_ID VARCHAR2(4) NOT NULL,
note_name VARCHAR2 (4)NOT NULL,
Note_Hours spent HOUR(4)NOT NULL,
Note_content VARCHAR2(254)NOT NULL,
Engineer_ID VARCHAR2(6)NOT NULL,
Bug_ID VARCHAR2(6)NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_Note PRIMARY KEY (Note_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_BugNoteID FOREIGN KEY(bug_ID) REFERENCES Bug(Bug_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_NoteEngineerID FOREIGN KEY(Engineer_ID) REFERENCES Engineer (Engineer_ID)

);

COMMIT;

CREATE TABLE Project_bug --Creating the Project bug table. 
(
Bug_ID VARCHAR2(6),
Project_ID VARCHAR2(8),
CONSTRAINT FK_bug_project_bugID FOREIGN KEY (Bug_ID) REFERENCES bug (bug_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_bug_project_projectID FOREIGN KEY (Project_ID) REFERENCES Project (Project_ID),
CONSTRAINT PK_Bug_Project PRIMARY KEY (Bug_ID, Project_ID),

);

COMMIT;

CREATE TABLE Allocation_fix--creating the allocation fix table. 
(
Engineer_ID VARCHAR2(6),
Bug_ID VARCHAR2(6),
CONSTRAINT FK_Engineer_FixAllocatedID FOREIGN KEY (Engineer_ID) REFERENCES Engineer (Engineer_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_Bug_FixAllocatedID FOREIGN KEY (Bug_ID) REFERENCES Bug (Bug_ID),
CONSTRAINT PK_Fix_Allocation PRIMARY KEY (Bug_ID, Engineer_ID)

);

COMMIT;


CREATE TABLE Allocation_test --creating the allocation test table.
( 
Engineer_ID VARCHAR2(6),
bug_ID VARCHAR2 (8),
CONSTRAINT FK_Engineer_TestAllocatedID FOREIGN KEY (Engineer_ID) REFERENCES Engineer (Engineer_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_Bug_TestAllocatedID FOREIGN KEY (Bug_ID) REFERENCES Bug (Bug_ID),
CONSTRAINT PK_Test_Allocation PRIMARY KEY (Bug_ID, Engineer_ID)

);

COMMIT;


--INSERT SCRIPTS

INSERT INTO bug VALUES ('B1','bug_1','first bug','6-DEC-98')
INSERT INTO bug VALUES ('B2','bug_2','second bug','7-DEC-98')
INSERT INTO bug VALUES ('B3','bug_3','third bug','8-DEC-98')
INSERT INTO bug VALUES ('B4','bug_4','fourth bug','9-DEC-98')
INSERT INTO bug VALUES ('B5','bug_5','fifth bug','10-DEC-98')
INSERT INTO bug VALUES ('B6','bug_6','sixth bug','11-DEC-98')


COMMIT;

INSERT INTO Engineer VALUES ('E1','Jones','Lee') --tester
INSERT INTO Engineer VALUES ('E2','Friend','Kane') --fixer
INSERT INTO Engineer VALUES ('E3','Ingham','Darcie') --tester
INSERT INTO Engineer VALUES ('E4','Jones','Carly') --fixer
INSERT INTO Engineer VALUES ('E5','Evergreen','Damien') --tester
INSERT INTO Engineer VALUES ('E6', 'Danes', 'Lucy') --showing the optionality of having an engineer that isnt a tester or a fixer

COMMIT;

INSERT INTO Note VALUES ('N1','Test1','4','testing was carried out by E1')
INSERT INTO Note VALUES ('N2','Fix1','5','fix was applied by E2')
INSERT INTO Note VALUES ('N3','Test2','7','testing was carried out by E1') 
INSERT INTO Note VALUES ('N4','Fix2','3','fix was applied by E3')
INSERT INTO Note VALUES ('N5','Test3','3','testing was carried out by E4')
INSERT INTO Note VALUES ('N6','Fix3','1','fix was applied by E5')
INSERT INTO Note VALUES ('N7','Test4','5','testing was carries out by E4') 
INSERT INTO Note VALUES ('N8','Fix4','9','fix was applied by E5')

COMMIT;

INSERT INTO project VALUES ('P1', 'Bethesda')
INSERT INTO project VALUES ('P2', 'Activsion')
INSERT INTO project VALUES ('P3', 'Valve')
INSERT INTO project VALUES ('P4', 'Mojang')
INSERT INTO project VALUES ('P5', 'Blizzard')
INSERT INTO project VALUES ('P6', 'Rockstar')

COMMIT;

INSERT INTO Project_bug VALUES ('B1', 'P1')
INSERT INTO Project_bug VALUES ('B2', 'P2')
INSERT INTO Project_bug VALUES ('B3', 'P3')
INSERT INTO Project_bug VALUES ('B4', 'P4')
INSERT INTO Project_bug VALUES ('B5', 'P5')
INSERT INTO Project_bug VALUES ('B6', 'P6')

COMMIT;

INSERT INTO Allocation_fix VALUES ('E1','B1' ) --this data set shows the optionality of engineers being "fixers" or "testers"
INSERT INTO Allocation_fix VALUES ('E2','B2')
INSERT INTO Allocation_fix VALUES ('E3','B3')
INSERT INTO Allocation_fix VALUES ('E4','B4')
INSERT INTO Allocation_fix VALUES ('E5','B5')
INSERT INTO Allocation_fix VALUES ('E1','B6')


COMMIT;

INSERT INTO Allocation_test VALUES ('E1','B1') -- this data set shows the optionality of engineers being "fixers" or "testers"
INSERT INTO Allocation_test VALUES ('E2','B2')
INSERT INTO Allocation_test VALUES ('E3','B3')
INSERT INTO Allocation_test VALUES ('E4','B4')
INSERT INTO Allocation_test VALUES ('E5','B5')
INSERT INTO Allocation_test VALUES ('E1','B6')

COMMIT;

--SELECT SCRIPTS

-- 1: List of all the bugs, and their details.

 SELECT*From bug;

-- Query 2 : List of all bugs, and their notes. 

 SELECT bug_type, note_id, note_content
 FROM bug,note 
 WHERE bug.bug_id=note.bug_id;

 -- Query 3 : List of all bugs, with their notes, and the engineers who have written them; sorted by name of engineer.

 SELECT bug.bug_id,bug_type, note_id, note_content, engineer.engineer_id, engineer_firstname, engineer_lastname
 FROM bug, note, engineer
 WHERE bug.bug_id=note.bug_id AND note.engineer_id=engineer.engineer_id
 ORDER BY engineer_lastname ASC;

 --Query 4: List the bugs and how much cumulative time (in hours) they have taken; ordered by time taken.

 SELECT bug.bug_id, SUM(note.hours_spent) 
 FROM note,bug
 WHERE bug.bug_id=note.bug_id
 GROUP BY bug.bug_id
 ORDER BY SUM(note.hours_spent) ASC;

  --Query 5 : The bug that has taken most time to fix and the projects it is connected to.

SELECT bug_taken_most_time_to_fix.bug_id, bug_project.project_id, bug_taken_most_time_to_fix."Total_Hours" FROM
(
      SELECT bug.bug_id, SUM(note.hours_spent) AS "Total_Hours"
  FROM note,bug
    WHERE bug.bug_id=note.bug_id
    GROUP BY bug.bug_id
    ORDER BY SUM(note.hours_spent) DESC FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
)
bug_taken_most_time_to_fix, bug_project
WHERE bug_taken_most_time_to_fix.bug_id = bug_project.bug_id; 

--DROP SCRIPTS

DROP TABLE allocation_test;
DROP TABLE allocation_fix;
DROP TABLE Project_bug;
DROP TABLE Note;
DROP TABLE Engineer;
DROP TABLE Bug;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Your code works fine [in this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=17efe6f24d83b115f9ce5c23d5b5da29).

Comment: Side note: you don't need to `commit` DDL operations such as `create table`.

Comment: oh? you see its for university, but my version of SQL on my laptop is throwing loads of errors about my code, now im hesitant to submit it, if youre saying it works fine but the version of oracle is throwing errors at me...

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you running?

Comment: on my laptop im running version 19.2.1.247

Comment: would i be able to message you about my code? im really hesitant now that its all gonna be wrong and im gonna fail this assignment now

Comment: 19.2.1.247 is probably sqldev version, not database version. Are you sure you do not have some kind of CRLF vs LF issue? (I take GMB's word that it ran without issue).

Comment: I notice that you've got a mix of `VARCHAR` and `VARCHAR2` definitions for the same fields. I know that this shouldn't be an issue, but when I took @GMB's fiddle and switched it to Oracle 18c it eventually gave back a "run failed' error from dbfiddle. If you're really on 19c you might want to make sure that all the data types used for all your fields agree everywhere. I wouldn't *expect* a data type issue to be reported as `missing right parenthesis`, but Oracle error messages are known to be pretty awful.

Comment: hey guys, ive just uploaded my entire code, im just looking for criticism now, and thank you! ill go through it now and change all the values to varchar2

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax error in your CREATE table syntax of note table. -

```
CREATE TABLE Note --Creating the note table. 
(
Note_ID VARCHAR2(4) NOT NULL,
note_name VARCHAR2 (4)NOT NULL,
Note_Hours_spent NUMBER(4)NOT NULL,
Note_content VARCHAR2(254)NOT NULL,
Engineer_ID VARCHAR2(6)NOT NULL,
Bug_ID VARCHAR2(6)NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_Note PRIMARY KEY (Note_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_BugNoteID FOREIGN KEY(bug_ID) REFERENCES Bug(Bug_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_NoteEngineerID FOREIGN KEY(Engineer_ID) REFERENCES Engineer (Engineer_ID)
);
```

And have a comma at the last of Project_bug table -

```
CREATE TABLE Project_bug --Creating the Project bug table. 
(
Bug_ID VARCHAR2(6),
Project_ID VARCHAR2(8),
CONSTRAINT FK_bug_project_bugID FOREIGN KEY (Bug_ID) REFERENCES bug (bug_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_bug_project_projectID FOREIGN KEY (Project_ID) REFERENCES Project (Project_ID),
CONSTRAINT PK_Bug_Project PRIMARY KEY (Bug_ID, Project_ID)
);
```

Last your insert statement into note table is giving error in [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6b6c0a3d28e52d770914a68d17462e05) fiddle as you do not have enough values to insert into that table.